# Laravel Model Binding

Tags: laravel, model

I have issue with model binding in routes and controller. Here is my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'services/devops/domain-names'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/editAutoRenew/{domainname}', 'EnomController@editAutoRenew');
    });        
    Route::post('/', 'EnomController@checkDomainName');
});
```

And here is function

```
public function editAutoRenew(DomainName $domainname)
{
    dd($domainname);
}
```

But this gives me empty model. Why? How can I get my model? 
I tried to route:list and there it shows {domainname}

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi yes, I wrote it in question description

Comment: okay: show us your DomainName model

Comment: Can you please show all yours routes when you do route:list?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi `namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DomainName extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['sld', 'tld','product_id','name', 'registrar_id', 'DomainNameId', 'user_id','invoice_id','transaction_id','subscription_id','creation_date','expiration_date','price','cost','auto_renew'];

    public function registrar()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Registrar::class);
    }
}`

Comment: @RubanrajRavichandran why u need to view all route:list?

Comment: Sometime it won't work if we keep our route list wrong order. That's why I asked, to check the route ordering is correct or not.

Comment: try this see if u are getting the value Route::get('/editAutoRenew/{domainname}', function (App\DomainName $domainname){
dd($domainname);
});

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi still shows empty

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi however, I got my model object through this `dd($domainname->first());`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @TalgatBaltasov if the primary key is not `id`, you have to define the model route key in the model using `public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'primary_key';
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You get in argument integer type, not object. Try to rewrite your function with:

```
public function editAutoRenew($domainname)
{
    $domainnameObj = DomainName::findOrFail($domainname);
}
```

When you use:

```
DomainName::first();
```

You get all entries from your table domain_name, then command first() - get first of this records.